# How to give each Process a certain array to start off with

Tags: java, mpi, mpj-express

I am new to both mpi and mpj express, and thus not knowledgeable enough in how to translate my idea in code. My Idea and code thus far revolve around a function calculating numbers to use and saving them in array, thus one process starts with numbers from x to y while another process starts with y+1 to z.

How would I go about giving each process that array before going onto a simple send & recv pattern.

I hope that my intentions are clear and understandable.

Answer (score 0):

You can different functions (**Broadcast, Scatter, Gather**) provided by MPJ Express. Online tutorials and detail about these functions is available at different websites. You can look at definitions about these functions provided by MPJ Express on [this link.](http://mpjexpress.org/docs/javadocs/index.html)